# Define takeword, dropword and words function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to Define a takeWord function in Haskell which takes a string and returns its first word. It should take each character at a time from the beginning to the end until the first space character. It should return the characters before the first space character. dropword function it is similar to takeword but drop the first word and take rest. wordsof function it is similar to words function in haskell.

```
takeword :: String -> String
takeword "" = ""
takeword (x:xs) = x : takeword xs
```

sample of result

```
*Main> takeword "abcdef"
"abcdef"
```

```
dropword :: String -> String
dropword "" = ""
dropword (' ': xs) = ""
dropword (x:xs) = drop length(takeword xs) takeword xs




wordsof :: String -> [[Char]]
wordsof "" = []
wordsof (x:xs) = takeword xs
wordsof x = splitOn (takeword x)
```

Comment: There isn't a question here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let's start with your definition:

```
takeword :: String -> String
takeword "" = ""
takeword (x:xs) = x : takeword xs
```

This does nothing to treat non-space characters and spaces differently. The first step would be to pattern match on spaces. So, let's split the second line into two cases:

```
takeword :: String -> String
takeword "" = ""
takeword (' ':xs) = error "TODO"  -- Spaces
takeword (x:xs) = x : takeword xs -- Non-spaces
```

Now, if we encounter a space, then clearly that's as far as we need to go, so at that point we can just return an empty string. After a bit of formatting, we get this:

```
takeword :: String -> String
takeword  ""      = ""
takeword (' ':xs) = ""
takeword (x  :xs) = x : takeword xs
```

And that's it. That's all there is to it. Here it is in action:

```
λ> takeword "Hello, World!"
"Hello,"
λ> takeword "This is a test."
"This"
λ> takeword "is a test."
"is"
```

---

***Exercise**: What if I wanted to split a string on the first word, so `splitOnWord "Hello, world of worlds!"` returns `("Hello,", "World of worlds!")`? This can be very easily written given the `takeword` function you already have.*

Comment: @mohamadJamal Also note there is a prelude function that does just this: `words :: String -> [String]`, and the  you can take the head

Answer (score 2):

Here's an even simpler solution:

```
takeword = takeWhile (' ' /=)
```

From the documentation:

> [`takeWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile), applied to a predicate p and a list xs, returns the longest prefix (possibly empty) of `xs` of elements that satisfy `p`

In this case, the predicate is testing that the element isn't a space. Thus, this will return the longest prefix that contains no spaces.